# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar una imagen de public_html?

Tags: laravel, hosting

Estoy atorado en lo siguiente, tengo un subdominio con aplicación de `Laravel`, ejemplo el proyecto se llama "laravel" y cuando guardo el archivo, se va a guardar a la carpeta `"/home/dominio/public_html/laravel/imagenes/"`, pero al momento que deseo acceder a la imagen (se que esta allí porque la puedo ver desde el administrador de archivos del `cpanel`) tengo en mi ruta:

```
<img src="/imagenes/{{$prod->imagen}}" alt="" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;">
```

Pero no me muestra nada, para guardar la imagen cambie el `path` por `$file>move('imagenes/',$nom_imagen);`

Y con eso funciona muy bien, pero si copio y pego lo de la ruta que use para guardarla, no funciona.

Si pueden ayudarme, se los agradeceré.

Comment: Me pasa exactamente lo mismo y aun no puedo solucionar, de forma local ningún problema pero al subir al Servidor Cpanel /home/NombreUsuario/NombreProyecto/public/storage (acceso directo storage funciona) pero en el servidor solo muestra lo que existe en public_html así /home/NombreUsuario/public_html/storage pero este storage no me sirve porque no accede a NombreProyecto que esta un directorio más atras /home/NombreUsuario/---- ------/NombreProyecto/public/storage ------/public_html/storage

Comment: Hola @Claudio, sientese libre de abrir otra pregunta, pero practicamente la solucion es crear un enlace simbolico:https://www.hostinger.es/tutoriales/crear-enlace-simbolico-linux

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/355514)

Answer (score 1):

si la imagen esta subida a internet, tendrias que usar el comando

pero no puedes darle click derecho y ya, tienes que abrir la imagen en una nueva ventana y cojer la url del sitio.
pero si solo tu la tienes en ese sitio, tendrias que escribir la ruta, pero de la pagina en cuestion, es decir, la url o carpeta.
Ejemplo: www.pagina.com/usuario1/disco/images/ 
eso me toco a mi.

Comment: fijate que ya intenté y no me funciona, como escribi tengo las imagenes en una carpeta del html_public que es "html_public/laravel/imagenes", algun otro metodo?

Answer (score 1):

te explico para mandar a llamar una imagen y no tener que estar cambiando de ruta a cada rato, laravel provee de una manera simple y sencilla de hacerlo de este modo

ejemplo:

```
{{ asset('img/favicon.png') }}
```

y en tu caso quedaria de la siguiente mandera

```
<img src="{{ asset('imgagenes/$prod->imagen') }}" alt="" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;">
```

Comment: Gracias, esto si me funciono, con el pequeño cambio de <img src="{{ asset('imagenes/'.$prod->imagen) }}" alt="" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;">

Comment: Me alegra que te allá funcionado @MauEspaña, y si fue la respuesta acertada, intenta marcarla con la Palomita para que tambien mas usuarios que tengan la misma duda puedan resolverla

Answer (score 1):

1.- Verificarste si la imagen existe?

ya que tienes que tenerlo en la carperta pública `public_html`

```
$file>move(public_path().'/imagenes/',$nom_imagen);
```

2.- Para poder acceder a la imagen o cualquier archivo

```
<img src="{{url('imagenes/'.$prod->imagen)}}" alt="" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;">
```

3.- si quieres que nadie acceda por la ruta, crea un evento con `jQuery` que evite el `click derecho`

Comment: te comento que al dejar public_path() me lo va a guardar a la carpeta public del proyecto, pero no al html_public que esta en la raiz del dominio

Comment: sube tu sistema de archivos de tu servidor, ya que si todo esta fuera de `public_html` no podras acceder con nada, o tendras que configurar `.htaccess`